# LU decomposition of invertible matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

> Let $M\in M(n\times n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $$M=\begin{pmatrix}a & c & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & d \\ e & a & c & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & d \\ 0 & e & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & d \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & c & d \\ 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & e & a & c \\ f & f & \ldots & \ldots & f & e & a\end{pmatrix}$$ and with $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $M$ and every one of its $(i,i)$-minors is invertible.
>   Show that the LU decomposition of $M$ is of the following form:
>   $$L=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\ e & 1 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & 0 \\ 0 & e & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & 0 \\ 0 & e & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & e & 1 & 0 \\ f & f & \ldots & \ldots & f & e & 1\end{pmatrix}, \;U=\begin{pmatrix}a & c & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & d \\ 0 & a & c & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & d \\ \vdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \vdots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & c & d \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & a & c \\ 0 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & a\end{pmatrix}$$

My problem is that, performing LU decomposition as usual, we get that $L_{2,1}=\frac{e}{a}$, since row $2$ minus $\frac{e}{a}$ times row $1$ gives us a $0$ in the first entry of row $2$. I'm guessing that one has to use the fact that $M$ and all its $(i,i)$-minors are invertible but I don't know how exactly I can use that fact here.

Comment: Does $d=0$ in $L$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yes, of course, I've edited the question, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You're saying in the comments that the point is to prove that $a=1$. **It's impossible.** Assume that it is possible, and multiply every entry in $M$ by $2$. Then every minor is multiplied by a power of $2$, so non-zero minors are still non-zero and every assumption is respected. But $a$ is not equal to $1$ any more.

---

Original answer:

It is immediate to see that the product of the provided $L,U$ matrices is not equal to $M$ unless $ea=e$, that is $e=0$ or $a=1$. The fact that all $(i,i)$ minors are invertible is unlikely to imply something as strong as $e=0$ or $a=1$ (and also it doesn't really make sense either, since you don't what $i$ is, and it clearly can't be true for all $i$, since there are zeroes in the matrix).

Comment: But $a=1$ is not given in the exercise and that's exactly the problem: Of course the statement doesn't hold if  $a\neq1$ but we still have to prove that $a=1$.

Comment: @user Okay. Do you have an explanation about the unknown $i$ as well? Maybe it's about the *leading principal minors*? Besides, it's impossible to prove that $a=1$ given the assumptions. See edit.

Comment: i is not unknown, it just says that every (i,i)-minor is invertible, which presumably means every minor where equal row and  column are deleted, is invertible, I guess.

Comment: @user With no additional information, this would imply that $n$ can't be very big, otherwise you can find minors full of zeroes.